# ¿Como se puede obtener datos de una tabla 1 que no se encuentre en la tabla2?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

como puedo hacer para obtener los datos de una tabla1 que no este en otra tabla2 y que sea diferente a un id (idmodseleccion) que se encuentra en la tabla2, estoy trabajando on 2 tablas que estan relacionadas, las cuales son:

```
Tabla 1: requisitos
idrequisito int (Clave primaria),
nombrerequisito varchar(25)

Tabla 2: modalidad_requisito
idmodrequisito int (Clave primaria),
idmodseleccion int,
idrequisito int
```

Estuve probando con la sentencia sql que no se encuentra (not exists)

```
SELECT * FROM requisitos r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM modalidad_requisitos mr 
   WHERE mr.idrequisito=r.idrequisito AND mr.idmodseleccion!=10)
```

pero el detalle es cuando la condiciono que sea diferente al idmodseleccion, si me pudieran dar una idea se lo agradecería.

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado

Comment: Esta utilizando esta sentencia: SELECT * FROM requisitos r WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM modalidad_requisitos mr WHERE mr.idrequisito=r.idrequisito AND mr.idmodseleccion!=10)

Comment: Edité tu pregunta añadiendo el SQL. Qué es lo que no te funciona? Qué te devuelve y qué debiera devolver?

Comment: Hola @Teresa. En preguntas de este tipo, es buena idea poner un pequeño ejemplo de los datos que están en cada tabla (digamos 2 o 3 filas para la primera y las que haga falta para la segunda) y el resultado que deseas obtener. Eso aclara mucho la idea, ya que de la explicación que das podrían haber distintas interpretaciones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a sustituir esto:

```
SELECT * FROM requisitos r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM modalidad_requisitos mr 
WHERE mr.idrequisito=r.idrequisito AND mr.idmodseleccion!=10)
```

Por esto:

```
SELECT * FROM requisitos r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM modalidad_requisito mr 
WHERE mr.idrequisito=r.idrequisito AND mr.idmodseleccion<>10)
```

Ojo!
Es "modalidad_requisito" y NO "modalidad_requisitos"

Answer (score 0):

si lo que estas buscando son los elementos de una tabla QUE NO estan en otra tabla, creo que deberias usar la sentencia NOT IN:

```
SELECT * FROM Requisitos r
WHERE r.idrequisito NOT IN (
    SELECT idrequisito FROM modalidad_requisito mr
    WHERE mr.idmodseleccion <> 10
)
```

esto coje todos los id de modalidad_requisitos que cumplen cierta condicion( en el ejemplo, que idmodseleccion sea distinto de 10). Luego, la consulta principal busca todos los Requisitos QUE NO TIENEN alguno de los indices que has conseguido en la subconsulta.